# Removing own answer instead of deleting it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

At times a user realizes that their answer was wrong or silly, and wants to remove it, since deleting it would still make it visible for high privilege users, and there is seemingly no useful effect accomplished by that. On the contrary, if a thread contains valuable answers, it would be harder to read and answer for high privileged users who see all deleted answers.

Why SE doesn't allow users to permanently physically remove (not delete) their own answers that didn't get upvotes or comments? I understand, they legally belong to SE, but what is the rational for not allowing to remove, unless in law enforcement cases? Would preserving the removed answers in SE backup be more rational rather then showing to high privileged users?

Comment: I'm not sure what rep your real account has, but I never had issues seeing deleted posts - they generally are way outside of regular answers (delete always sorted last) and don't show up as questions... So not really clear to me what problem you suggest to solve.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Then I have to ask you, whether you consider yourself a discovery reporter or user helper? Imaging, some folks present their creative accomplishments on SO rather then answering day-to-day plain vanilla questions. :) But again, note this is a Question. I just wanted to clarify the backgrounder.

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov: For me it is clear enough - finally delelete/remove the question, so that nobody can see it. And link/reference on it should return 404 ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is the Internet - you can never completely delete things. There are always tools like the Wayback Machine to retrieve deleted content.

Note that deleted posts do count against a potential question/answer ban. It will be hard to point to 'evidence' if it is not there anymore. Also, deleted posts might be mentioned by other answers (e.g. 'an alternative solution to the one proposed by @sambul35, or, 'contrary to what @sambul35 says'), which then become invalid.

In extreme cases, you can ask for your account to be *disassociated* from certain posts, so that they will appear as being posted by an anonymous user.

> it would be harder to read and answer for high privileged users who see all deleted answers.

Deleted answers are always displayed at the bottom, so they don't cause any clutter. They can't be acted (voted / commented) upon, so they don't draw any attention.

Comment: I understand they may be preserved in some SE backup archives, seen by mods, but why show them on the front page for high privileged users? Is their any purpose for that, if the owner wants to remove the answer?

Comment: Deleted or disassociated content is unlikely to receive the kind and amount of attention you fear

Comment: I don't really fear of anything, but wanted to give an example. A few high knowledge users posted some interesting discussion about a certain subject. A novice would add his answer, and then realizes its wrong. Now all these users are upset because they see the deleted answer every time reading the thread. Next time they are less likely to answer your questions due to that. :) And its indeed harder to navigate a thread with many deleted answers showing up in front of useful info.

Comment: @sambul35: you are overestimating the sensitivity of high rep users. Most deleted posts are utter crap. Every now and then I wish I could turn off this X ray vision into Stack Overflow's sewer system.

Comment: @RadLexus you could use User Stylesheets for that.

Comment: That's exactly what I suggest - at least an option to turn it off for high privilege users. I don't however overestimate the neg effect. Some folks I know get irritated when someone they know posts such "crap", so next time they don't want to help. Its rather typical in cases, when a thread is created to present a new discovery, and the author wants to keep it clean and sharp.

Comment: @Glorfindel Re "evidence" issue, if a user self withdrawn an answer, I don't know if it makes sense to count as evidence of violation, at least in every such case. Its probably "case-by-case" treated anyway, no need to show forever in the thread, as "evidence" is assessed only by mods and staff, but not actionable by high privileged users.

Comment: @Glorfindel Not sure how my deleted answer is presented to others, but I can see it on top of all other answers every time I read the thread, and get irritated as well. :) Can you link a Stylesheet that filters them out?

Comment: And again silly effect of hiding from other Meta readers user questions that contain certain proposals to change current rules, or point to perceived deficiencies in practices. Instead of discussing them, as they don't do any harm to the site, they are often immediately hidden from the public by close votes, as I expect here. And the practice to ask in Chat to join Closure or Delete process at times resembles wolfs conduct, it should be discouraged by rules. :)

Comment: Jeff Atwood in the [last post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14117/answers-quickly-deleted-by-owner-should-be-permanently-deleted/117390#117390) suggested a useful alternative to removing an answer by filling it with a few words (despite edit history remains), but didn't explain why there is no option to remove the answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel _"This is the Internet ..."_ Browser manufacturers should be forced by law to put a **big banner** like that every time when a user uploads any content. ;-) .... There are less and less responsible persons it seems nowadays.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ IMHO, it should be part of upbringing. Most (vulnerable) content nowadays is uploaded via Snapchat and Instagram.

Comment: so @sambul35. This is gonna sound curt and down to Earth... but : Changing this behavior will require dev time (however little that may be). Dev time is EXTREMELY valuable. What real benefit does your proposal have? Very little as well (except for you, those answers are ALWAYS displayed at the bottom, so not likely to piss off that many people). I don't think it's worth spending dev cycles on something like this.

Comment: @Patrice The site cleanup is positioned as major strategic task, and soooo many folks are engaged in this daily. I don't believe this was the real reason, and the reason was never publicly explained, if you follow Jeff's citation above.

Comment: @sambul35 your answer doesnt appear to most members, and to those it appears for, it's not in the way. The site IS clean. YOU assume people get pissed seeing those. In any case, right now,to change the behavior, you'll need dev time. And right now, to get dev time, you need to convince people this is worth spending the time....

Comment: I think you're right. "_there is no concept of hard deletion of answers. It simply doesn't exist, and never has._" Unclear, but it looks like not enough justification to this was evident, when the site foundations were set. Back then it wouldn't take extra cost to implement, as it was ground 0. Now it will add some cost, since the site code is so complex and interdependent. :)